# Only half of RAM is seen

Tags: windows, memory, bios, dual-channel

I have two Crucial RAM sticks which I put in two slots which are supposed to work dual-channel. BIOS sees both of them, but in total is showing only half:
[image]

CPU-Z shows 8GB of RAM, but Windows 10 only 4.
If I put the sticks in single channel mode (slots A1/A2 for example) all 8GB are recognized by Windows.

Is this a main board failure and nothing can be done?

Changing the frequency does not help. As putting the sticks in other slots:
[image]

Here is part of CPU-Z report:

```
Chipset
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Northbridge         AMD K15 IMC rev. 00
Southbridge         AMD A88X FCH rev. 2.6
Graphic Interface       PCI-Express
PCI-E Link Width        x0
PCI-E Max Link Width        x0
Memory Type         DDR3
Memory Size         8 GBytes
Channels            Single
Memory Frequency        666.5 MHz (3:20)
CAS# latency (CL)       9.0
RAS# to CAS# delay (tRCD)   9
RAS# Precharge (tRP)        9
Cycle Time (tRAS)       24
Bank Cycle Time (tRC)       29
Uncore Frequency        1799.6 MHz


Memory SPD
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

DIMM #              1
    SMBus address       0x50
    Memory type     DDR3
    Module format       UDIMM
    Manufacturer (ID)   Crucial Technology (7F7F7F7F7F9B0000000000)
    Size            4096 MBytes
    Max bandwidth       PC3-10700H (667 MHz)
    Part number     BLT4G3D1869DT1TX0.
    Serial number       A4133449
    Number of banks     8
    Nominal Voltage     1.50 Volts
    EPP         no
    XMP         yes
    XMP revision        1.3
    AMP         no
JEDEC timings table     CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
    JEDEC #1        6.0-6-6-16-22 @ 444 MHz
    JEDEC #2        8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 592 MHz
    JEDEC #3        9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 666 MHz
XMP profile         XMP-1866
    Specification       PC3-14900
    Voltage level       1.500 Volts
    Min Cycle time      1.071 ns (933 MHz)
    Max CL          9.0
    Min tRP         9.43 ns
    Min tRCD        9.43 ns
    Min tWR         15.00 ns
    Min tRAS        28.14 ns
    Min tRC         49.50 ns
    Min tRFC        160.00 ns
    Min tRTP        7.50 ns
    Min tRRD        6.00 ns
    Command Rate        2T
XMP timings table       CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC-CR @ frequency (voltage)
    XMP #1          6.0-6-6-18-32-2T @ 636 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #2          7.0-7-7-21-37-2T @ 742 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #3          8.0-8-8-24-42-2T @ 848 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #4          9.0-9-9-27-47-2T @ 933 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #5          10.0-9-9-27-47-2T @ 933 MHz (1.500 Volts)

DIMM #              2
    SMBus address       0x51
    Memory type     DDR3
    Module format       UDIMM
    Manufacturer (ID)   Crucial Technology (7F7F7F7F7F9B0000000000)
    Size            4096 MBytes
    Max bandwidth       PC3-10700H (667 MHz)
    Part number     BLT4G3D1869DT1TX0.
    Serial number       A019CA21
    Number of banks     8
    Nominal Voltage     1.50 Volts
    EPP         no
    XMP         yes
    XMP revision        1.3
    AMP         no
JEDEC timings table     CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC @ frequency
    JEDEC #1        6.0-6-6-16-22 @ 444 MHz
    JEDEC #2        8.0-8-8-22-30 @ 592 MHz
    JEDEC #3        9.0-9-9-24-33 @ 666 MHz
XMP profile         XMP-1866
    Specification       PC3-14900
    Voltage level       1.500 Volts
    Min Cycle time      1.071 ns (933 MHz)
    Max CL          9.0
    Min tRP         9.43 ns
    Min tRCD        9.43 ns
    Min tWR         15.00 ns
    Min tRAS        28.14 ns
    Min tRC         49.50 ns
    Min tRFC        160.00 ns
    Min tRTP        7.50 ns
    Min tRRD        6.00 ns
    Command Rate        2T
XMP timings table       CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS-tRC-CR @ frequency (voltage)
    XMP #1          6.0-6-6-18-32-2T @ 636 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #2          7.0-7-7-21-37-2T @ 742 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #3          8.0-8-8-24-42-2T @ 848 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #4          9.0-9-9-27-47-2T @ 933 MHz (1.500 Volts)
    XMP #5          10.0-9-9-27-47-2T @ 933 MHz (1.500 Volts)

DIMM #              1
SPD registers   
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  93 13 0B 02 03 19 00 09 03 52 01 08 0C 00 34 00 
    10  6C 78 6C 30 6C 11 20 8C 00 05 3C 3C 00 F0 82 05 
    20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F 11 01 01 
    40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    60  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    70  00 00 00 00 00 85 9B 00 00 00 A4 13 34 49 B8 8F 
    80  42 4C 54 34 47 33 44 31 38 36 39 44 54 31 54 58 
    90  30 2E 01 00 80 2C 42 5A 41 48 39 57 4D 30 30 31 
    A0  FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    B0  0C 4A 01 13 01 0E 00 00 11 2A 0F 84 7C 00 84 84 
    C0  84 D2 21 8A B5 6D 00 C0 08 69 54 01 A4 69 00 00 
    D0  1C 00 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

DIMM #              2
SPD registers   
        00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
    00  93 13 0B 02 03 19 00 09 03 52 01 08 0C 00 34 00 
    10  6C 78 6C 30 6C 11 20 8C 00 05 3C 3C 00 F0 82 05 
    20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F 11 01 01 
    40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    60  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    70  00 00 00 00 00 85 9B 00 00 00 A0 19 CA 21 B8 8F 
    80  42 4C 54 34 47 33 44 31 38 36 39 44 54 31 54 58 
    90  30 2E 01 00 80 2C 42 5A 41 48 39 57 4D 30 30 31 
    A0  FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    B0  0C 4A 01 13 01 0E 00 00 11 2A 0F 84 7C 00 84 84 
    C0  84 D2 21 8A B5 6D 00 C0 08 69 54 01 A4 69 00 00 
    D0  1C 00 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 


Monitoring
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Mainboard Model     A88X-PRO (0x00000227 - 0x00A0C942)



DMI
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

DMI BIOS        
    vendor          American Megatrends Inc.
    version         2603
    date            03/10/2016
    ROM size        8192 KB

DMI System Information      
    manufacturer        System manufacturer
    product         System Product Name
    version         System Version
    serial          System Serial Number
    UUID            {6B64AB80-15C6-11E0-A92A-40167EAD028F}
    SKU         SKU
    family          To be filled by O.E.M.

DMI Baseboard       
    vendor          ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    model           A88X-PRO
    revision        Rev X.0x
    serial          140525890700221

DMI System Enclosure        
    manufacturer        Chassis Manufacture
    chassis type        Desktop
    chassis serial      Chassis Serial Number
```

Comment: Have you tried them in slots A1/B1 rather than A2/B2?

Comment: Also note that the bios is reporting 4GB total at the top.

Comment: Notice that the Total Memory says 1866MHz but the DIMMs installed appear to be 1333MHz parts. Change whatever setting necessary to get it to operate the RAM at 1333 MHz instead.

Comment: I've updated the question. It worked originally when I bought the computer. Then it stopped, I don't remember any incidents. And RAM supports 1833 MHz.

Comment: Here is a very similar thread: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1852181/asus-a88xm-dual-channel-ram-problem.html

Comment: As it used to work, I suggest that you make a note of any BIOS (UEFI) settings that you've changed from the default values and then reset the BIOS. I assume you have a current backup of your data, just in case it all goes horribly wrong ;)

Comment: It turns out slots B1/B2 are not working at all. If I put both sticks into them, the comp doesn't boot. So it's a mobo or cpu defect. I'll look at the cpu pins when I have time, maybe they are damaged. Resetting BIOS' settings didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out slots B1/B2 are not working correctly. If I put both sticks into them, the comp doesn't boot. So it's a mobo or cpu defect. I'll look at the cpu pins when I have time, maybe they are damaged.